# Фоновая работа приложения PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Имеется проект для изучения слов через уведомления. И вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать фоновую работу уведомлений?

UPD:
Скрин главного окна (простой qt designer)
[image: Главное окно]

Скрин окна уведомления (тоже просто оболочка)
[image: окно уведомлений]

Подразумевается, что уведомления будут работать, когда запущено главное окно, т.е. мне нужно реализовать фоновую работу главного окна

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] того что у вас есть и лучше расскажите что вам надо сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick, обновил

Comment: то, что вы показали изображения - это хорошо, но я у вас спрашивал о минимально-воспроизводимом примере. То что вы нарисовали форма в Qt Designer - это тоже хорошо, но есть ли у вас какой-то код или задумки по логике приложения. Вы что-то должны набрать, например какое-то слово и что-то нажать, а затем откуда-то взять текст, который надо показать в уведомлении или как?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что именно вас интересует, но если вы хотите чтобы что-то работало в фоновом режиме используйте встроенный модуль `threading`.

Вот пример работы:

```
import threading #Импортируем модуль

#Создаем декоратор
def thread(my_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        my_thread.start()
    return wrapper

# И дальше вам достаточно просто написать @thread над той функцией которая 
# должна работать в фоновом режиме. Например:

@thread
def your_func():
    pass
```